PyQGIS error: "Ui_MainWindow" not defined
I built a dialog window on QtDesigner, converted this file .Ui into .py and I've tried to run on Qgis, but after some attempts with good results, the program says to me: "Ui_MainWindow" not defined, if I try running further time, QGis always crashes. I post the code
`from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listaFunzioni = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.listaFunzioni.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 781, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.listaFunzioni.setFont(font)
        self.listaFunzioni.setObjectName("listaFunzioni")
        self.listaFunzioni.addItem("")
        self.listaFunzioni.addItem("")
        self.listaFunzioni.addItem("")
        self.listaFunzioni.addItem("")
        self.listaFunzioni.addItem("")
        self.pulsanteAvvia = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pulsanteAvvia.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 370, 201, 51))
        self.pulsanteAvvia.setObjectName("pulsanteAvvia")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 30, 291, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.pulsanteAvvia.clicked.connect(self.cliccato)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def cliccato (self):
        scelta = self.listaFunzioni.currentText()
        if scelta == "Trova il terremoto più intenso nell'area":
            print(scelta)
            trovaTerremotoPiuForte()
        elif scelta == "Scopri tutti gli epicentri all'interno dell'area":
            trovaTerremoti()
        elif scelta == "Calcola l'intensità media di tutti i terremoti nell'area":
            intensitaMediaTerremoti()
        elif scelta == "Calcola l'intervallo medio tra terremoti al di sopra di una certa intensità":
            intervalloMedioTerremoti()
        elif scelta == "Calcola l'intervallo medio tra la ricostruzione di un edificio e un terremoto precedentemente":
            intervalloEdificioTerremoto()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.listaFunzioni.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Trova il terremoto più                intenso nell\'area"))
        self.listaFunzioni.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Scopri tutti gli epicentri all\'interno dell\'area"))
        self.listaFunzioni.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Calcola l\'intensità media di tutti i terremoti nell\'area"))
        self.listaFunzioni.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Calcola l\'intervallo medio tra terremoti al di sopra di una certa intensità"))
        self.listaFunzioni.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Calcola l\'intervallo medio tra la ricostruzione di un edificio e un terremoto precedente"))
        self.pulsanteAvvia.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Avvia"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Scegli la funzione"))

    


    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    

    




Thanks for your answers.

Could you provide the Traceback of your error, please?
